# "_form.erb.html" partial not working for create and update form code generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the Getting Started with Rails tutorial with a slight modification (on the name of the models and attributes) but I found a problem using the form partials.

My "_form.erb.html" looks as follows:

```
<%= form_for :company do |f| %>
    <% if @company.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@company.errors.count, "error") %> evitaron que la compañía se almacenara
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @company.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <div class="input">
        <%= f.label :name, "Nombre" %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true%>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <%= f.label :handle, "Handle" %>
        <%= f.text_field :handle, :required => true%>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <%= f.submit "Guardar" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My edit.html.erb looks like this:

```
<h1>Editar empresa</h1>
<hr>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Regresar al listado', companies_path %>
```

And the new.html.erb looks like this:

```
<h1>Nueva empresa</h1>
<hr>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Regresar al listado', companies_path %>
```

Previously without the partial I was using the following code for the form headers:

```
new.html.erb
<%= form_for :company, url: companies_path do |f| %>

edit.html.erb
<%= form_for :company, url: company_path(@company), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

Now that I'm trying to use the partial I get the following exception:

```
No route matches [POST] "/companies/new"

Rails.root: /../app

╔═══════════════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║      Helper       ║        HTTP Verb         ║             Path              ║ Controller#Action ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ Path / Url        ║                          ║                               ║                   ║
║ companies_path    ║ GET                      ║ /companies(.:format)          ║ companies#index   ║
║ POST              ║ /companies(.:format)     ║ companies#create              ║                   ║
║ new_company_path  ║ GET                      ║ /companies/new(.:format)      ║ companies#new     ║
║ edit_company_path ║ GET                      ║ /companies/:id/edit(.:format) ║ companies#edit    ║
║ company_path      ║ GET                      ║ /companies/:id(.:format)      ║ companies#show    ║
║ PATCH             ║ /companies/:id(.:format) ║ companies#update              ║                   ║
║ PUT               ║ /companies/:id(.:format) ║ companies#update              ║                   ║
║ DELETE            ║ /companies/:id(.:format) ║ companies#destroy             ║                   ║
║ pages_index_path  ║ GET                      ║ /pages/index(.:format)        ║ pages#index       ║
║ root_path         ║ GET                      ║ /                             ║ pages#index       ║
╚═══════════════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Any ideas on how to use the partial?

Comment: How did you _draw_ route table ? It looks nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it

```
<%= form_for @company do |f| %>
```

instead of

```
<%= form_for :company do |f| %>
```

From the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide:

> Everything except for the form_for declaration remained the same. The
>   reason we can use this shorter, simpler form_for declaration to stand
>   in for either of the other forms is that @article is a resource
>   corresponding to a full set of RESTful routes, and Rails is able to
>   infer which URI and method to use.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is really that you were using a symbol as the argument to `form_for` and then manually specifying the path to the controller action you wanted. But, now that you have refactored the `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` forms into a single partial (`_form.html.erb`), that won't work.

You want the form to submit a `post` request to the `/companies` path in the case of a new company, and a `put` request to the `companies/:id` path in the case of editing an existing company. Instead, it is submitting a `post` request to the new action.

You need to pass the `@company` instance variable from your views so that the form can use it:

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Nueva empresa</h1>
<hr>
<%= render 'form', company: @company %>
<%= link_to 'Regresar al listado', companies_path %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Editar empresa</h1>
<hr>
<%= render 'form', company: @company %>
<%= link_to 'Regresar al listado', companies_path %>
```

Change your form code to use the instance variable, like this:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @company do |f| %>
```

The `form_for` method is checking whether the object you gave as an argument is persisted or not. If it isn't, Rails knows you want the create action and makes the submit button go to that action, if it is persisted, Rails knows you want the update action.

Just make sure that you are passing the `@company` instance variable to the view in the first place:

**CompaniesController.rb**

```
def new
  @company = Company.new
end

def edit
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
end
```